# Web developer who can incorporate Latex code into website

Tags: tex-core

I want to make a website in which a lot of maths is involved. I am searching a website developer who can incorporate maths equations, questions etc in my website using Latex. Where can I get such a web developer?

Comment: It's not so difficult, most web developers (including those that do not know what LaTeX is) can probably implement MathJax (http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/start.html). Note that MathJax is not the same as LaTeX, but it is sufficient for most cases of displaying equations on websites.